# Why does `std::ranges::clamp` limits the number of projections so strictly?

Tags: c++, time-complexity, c++20, std-ranges

According to [[alg.clamp#5]](https://eel.is/c++draft/alg.clamp#5), the time complexity of [`std::ranges::clamp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/clamp) requires at most 2 comparisons and **3** application of projections. The possible implementation in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/clamp) is given by:

```
struct clamp_fn {
  template<class T, class Proj = std::identity,
           std::indirect_strict_weak_order<std::projected<const T*, Proj>> Comp = ranges::less>
  constexpr const T& operator()(const T& v, const T& lo, const T& hi,
                                Comp comp = {}, Proj proj = {}) const
  {
      assert(!std::invoke(comp, std::invoke(proj, hi), std::invoke(proj, lo)));
      return  std::invoke(comp, std::invoke(proj,  v), std::invoke(proj, lo)) ? lo
            : std::invoke(comp, std::invoke(proj, hi), std::invoke(proj,  v)) ? hi : v;
  }
};
 
inline constexpr clamp_fn clamp;
```

which obviously does not meet the requirements, since it involves 3 comparisons and **6** projections. Even if we comment out the `assert`, the number of projections is still **4** because `std::invoke(proj, v)` was executed twice.

The only way I can think of is to temporarily store the result of `std::invoke(proj, v)`, then pass it to the next two `comp` calls, just like the [libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/trunk/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/ranges_algo.h#L3220) does:

```
auto&& __proj_val = std::__invoke(__proj, __val);
if (std::__invoke(__comp, __proj_val, std::__invoke(__proj, __lo)))
  return __lo;
else if (std::__invoke(__comp, std::__invoke(__proj, __hi), __proj_val))
  return __hi;
else
  return __val;
```

But for safety, we seem to be unable to use `std::forward<decltype(__proj_val)>(__proj_val)` to perfect forward the `__proj_val` in the first `comp` call, which means that we seem to be unable to use **only 3** projections to *perfectly* implemented the `std::ranges::clamp`.

Why does `std::ranges::clamp` limits the number of projections so strictly? Does this mean that it is necessary to temporarily store the result of projection for the complexity requirement? Or is my understanding of this complexity requirement wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very much intentional. I asked specifically about this complexity requirement during the LWG review of the paper in Prague because it outlaws the "obvious" implementation. And yes, this requires the implementation to invoke the projection on the value and "suspend the result in mid-air" with `auto&&` or equivalent.

It also requires perfect forwarding the projected value (which libstdc++ fails to do). This is valid because the `invoke` expression is required to not modify its arguments (a requirement that comes from `regular_invocable`), and is required because nothing in `indirect_strict_weak_order` requires invocability with `iter_reference_t<I1>&`, only `iter_reference_t<I1>` and `iter_value_t<I1>&`.

Comment: Wait, the standard requires you (assuming project returns a value) initialize a value once and move it twice here?  Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I think you can get away with not moving it if the return type is cv-unqualified (since in that case for `projected` it's the same as the value type and we do require `iter_value_t&` to work). But if the projection produces, say, a `const T` then the comparison is only required to support `T` lvalues and `const T` rvalues, while without moving you would be calling with a `const T` lvalue. In any event, the comparison is required to not modify its arguments, even when said arguments are rvalues, so moving it twice is safe.

Comment: if the comparison *takes by value* it is the calling code that causes the modification in the move constructor, not the comparison.

Comment: It's the `invoke` expression that required to not modify. Since `invoke` always takes by reference, any modification happens inside that expression.

Comment: Is there an example of projection and predicate that demonstrates that predicate is indeed not callable without applying `std::forward` to stored temporary? I tried all combinations of cv-ref return values of projection but proper predicate is callable with all of them (when they satisfy requirements). Could you help me to find such an example?

Answer (score 1):

Forwarding is conditional move.  Move means "I do not need this value any more".  Recomputing a value only so we can move it more often is silly; our choice is create 2 and move both, or create 1, use it, then move it when done.